# WinRT Clear Clipboard background task

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

My app gives users the ability to clear a their clipboard after a certain time in seconds after copying some secure text.  The problem is, if the app suspends, the clipboard never clears.  I've looked at using a background task but I can't find a trigger that suits my needs.

Any advice?

Comment: Instead of adding the data and then later trying to revoke it, do it in reverse: Place the data on the clipboard [as a pull operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770848.aspx). When somebody ass for data, check the time and return an empty string if too much time has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

A [background task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx) is your best bet, but you have limited options. Ideally you would use a 15 minute timer, but you must be added to the lock screen and I suspect not many users would do that. The 2 hour timer might be your next best option.

A maintenance trigger would be a good option (as that is every 15 minutes and doesn't need to be on the lock screen), but it does require the device to not be on battery power.